# Using make to generate bison grammar

Tags: makefile, bison, compilation

In a project that uses `make` and `bison`, I'm having difficulty specifying that the compiled grammar `grammar.tab.c` depends on the grammar input `grammar.y`, that each object file depends on a corresponding source file (including `grammar.tab.o`), and that the executable depends on all object files.

The problem is that running `make` when grammar.tab.c does not yet exist means that there is no attempt to build it, and when the executable is built the `yyparse` function is missing.

My `Makefile` is:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
YACC = bison -d -r all
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS=grammar.tab.h hex.h compiler.h types.h

all: grammar.tab.h c

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) *.tab.c *.tab.h c c.exe *.output

c: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS)

grammar.tab.c: grammar.y
    $(YACC) grammar.y

grammar.tab.h: grammar.y
    $(YACC) grammar.y

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

If I change it with:

```
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c)) grammar.tab.o
```

Then it will build the compiled grammar if it doesn't already exist.  But if it does already exist, then
when building the executable, there will be an error about `yyparse` being provided twice (presumably because `$OBJ` contains `grammar.tab.o` twice).

What I'm aiming for is a Makefile that:

1. Will correctly build the executable on a `make` command, rebuilding intermediate files as necessary.
2. Will pick up all `*.c` files in the directory (i.e. doesn't need to be changed when new source files are added).
3. Is easy to read and understand.  I don't mind learning new `make` features as long as it's only one or two at a time.

How do others' grammar-building Makefiles work?

**Edit** Ok, those are great answers.  I went with the filter-out one, since it was the smallest change.  I'm really glad that everyone seemed to know exactly what I'm talking about -- I was apprehensive about being told to use something byzantine like automake ;-).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GNU make, you can use the filter-out predicate to manually exclude a particular file from the dependencies of a target.  Like so: `OBJ=$(filter-out $(grammar.tab.o), $(patsubst %.c, %.o, ...)) grammar.tab.o`.

You first exclude grammar.tab.o from the existing object files (it might not be there), then add it back in all cases.  Admittedly a bit roundabout, but it works.  That's what we use at work.

Answer (score 5):

For the general 'run yacc' rule you want something like

```
%.tab.c: %.y
        $(YACC) $<

%.tab.h: %.tab.c
        @touch $@
```

To get all the sources you want

```
OBJ=$(sort $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c)) $(patsubst %.y, %.tab.o, $(wildcard *.y)))
```

You need the 'sort' mostly for its automatic removal of duplicates

Comment: What makes you think I didn't? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
# you can consolidate both rules into one:
grammar.tab.c grammar.tab.h: grammar.y
        $(YACC) grammar.y

# but I find ``make'' more workable without many-to-one target-to-prerequisites
grammar.tab.c: grammar.tab.h
        touch $@
grammar.tab.h: grammar.y
        $(YACC) $<


# your problem, though, does seem to be with linking ``grammar.tab.o''

# you can exclude grammar.tab.o
OBJ =: $(filter-out grammar.tab.o,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))) grammar.tab.o

# you can remove duplicates from $(OBJ)
OBJ =: $(sort $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c)) grammar.tab.o)

# you can remove duplicates when linking
c: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(sort $^) $(LDLIBS)

# but personally, I prefer not to use $(wildcard) at all,
# explicitly updating the makefile as needed
```

Comment: I have wondered whether a largish but simple Makefile that spells out correct and minimal dependencies for all files would be a good approach to take.  Something to consider if things get more complicated, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Something like this... you'll have to play around with it. This is kind-sort-a how
I did this in the 90's... it's unconventional but served its purpose

SRCS          = foo.c bar.c lex.c yacc.c
OBJS          = $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.o)
OBJS.d        = $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.d)
CC_RULE       = $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
YACC_RULE     = cd $(@D); $(YACC) $(YFLAGS) -o $(@F) $<
LEX_RULE      = cd $(@D); $(LEX) $(LEXFLAGS) -o$(@F) $<
CC_DEP_RULE   = @echo -n "$(@D)/" > $@;
CC_DEP_RULE   += gcc -M $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $< |
CC_DEP_RULE   += sed -e 's@:@: $(MAKEFILE_DEPS) @' >> $@;

$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.o: $(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC_RULE)

$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.c: $(SRC_DIR)/%.l
     $(LEX_RULE)

$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.c: $(SRC_DIR)/%.y
    $(YACC_RULE)

$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC_RULE)

$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.d: $(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC_DEP_RULE)

$(OBJ_DEST_DIR)/%.d: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC_DEP_RULE)

-include $(OBJS.d)
```

This is what one of the .d files will look like

```
/tmp/builds/objs/opt/libiberty/static/alloca.o:   /tmp/src/binutils-2.20/libiberty/alloca.c \
  /tmp/src/binutils-2.20/libiberty/config.h \
  /tmp/src/binutils-2.20/include/libiberty.h \
  /tmp/src/binutils-2.20/include/ansidecl.h \
  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/stddef.h \
  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/stdarg.h \
  /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/_types.h /usr/include/sys/_types.h \
  /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h /usr/include/machine/_types.h \
  /usr/include/i386/_types.h /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h \
  /usr/include/secure/_common.h /usr/include/string.h \
  /usr/include/secure/_string.h /usr/include/stdlib.h \
  /usr/include/Availability.h /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h \
  /usr/include/sys/wait.h /usr/include/sys/signal.h \
  /usr/include/sys/appleapiopts.h /usr/include/machine/signal.h \
  /usr/include/i386/signal.h /usr/include/i386/_structs.h \
  /usr/include/sys/_structs.h /usr/include/machine/_structs.h \
  /usr/include/mach/i386/_structs.h /usr/include/sys/resource.h \
  /usr/include/machine/endian.h /usr/include/i386/endian.h \
  /usr/include/sys/_endian.h /usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h \
  /usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h /usr/include/alloca.h \
  /usr/include/machine/types.h /usr/include/i386/types.h \
```

You can play around with the MAKEFILE_DEPS variable to insert other dependencies too